# Ember nf-graphs bars only displays one bar in first column

Tags: ember.js

I have the following input data for a bars graph but for some reason the bars only display in one column:

```
menuItemStockCount: [
    { x: 0, y: 200 },
    { x: 1, y: 154 },
    { x: 2, y: 130 },
    { x: 3, y: 300 }
]
```

My code in my .hbs file to display the graph is:

```
{{#nf-graph width=500 
            height=300 
            paddingRight=10 
            paddingTop=10 
            xScaleType="ordinal" 
            yMinMode="fixed" 
            yMin=0
            showLanes=true
            showFrets=true
            }}
    {{#nf-graph-content}}

        {{nf-bars data=model.menuItemStockCount
                       trackingMode="snap-last"
                       trackedData=tracked}}    

    {{/nf-graph-content}}

    {{#nf-y-axis as |tick|}}
        <text>{{tick.value}}</text>
    {{/nf-y-axis}}

    {{#nf-x-axis as |tick|}}
        <text>{{tick.value}}</text>
    {{/nf-x-axis}}

{{/nf-graph}}

<text>{{tracked.x}} {{tracked.y}}</text>
```

Am I just doing something wrong?

Comment: A failing bin at emberjs.jsbin.com would help

Comment: Hi, I can't find a way to add nf-graphs as n script link on jsbin since I installed on my PC and never had to add the '<script></script>' links.

Comment: So I contacted the developers regarding this issue and they told me it was bug. It is fixed in the new version